# Problem trying to import PFX certificate in asp .NET Core

Tags: c#, certificate, digital-signature, x509certificate, pfx

I'm creating a program with ASP .NET Core MVC, which signs PDFs with a digital signature. And I use a digital certificate PFX file created by windows powershell which should be loaded by the application and used to sign the PDF, but I can't load the PFX because of some privacy issue.

this is the problem that appears at the time of the bug:

*An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
WindowsCryptographicException: unspecified error
Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(byte[] rawData, string fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)*

*WindowsCryptographicException: unspecified error
Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(byte[] rawData, string fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(string fileName, string password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
Spire.Pdf.Security.PdfCertificate..ctor(string pfxPath, string password)*

**what is this problem and how to solve it?**

some additional information that might be useful, this PFX file was created on another computer and I emailed it to myself and downloaded it to my computer, because for some reason I can't use Windows powershell correctly to create the certificate on my own machine.

small part of code until the bug line:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            string nome = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("NomeUsLog");
            string path = "";
            string filename ="Oxen" + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Upload"));
            string pathUsuario = Path.Combine(path, nome);
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var filestream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(pathUsuario, filename), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(filestream);
                }


                    //Create a PdfDocument object

                PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();


                //Load a sample PDF file
                string filePath = Path.Combine(pathUsuario, filename);
                doc.LoadFromFile(filePath);


                //Load the certificate 
                //on this line the bug occurs
                PdfCertificate cert = new PdfCertificate(pathUsuario, "CertificadoDig.pfx");
```

Comment: If you have hosted this in IIS, select Application Pool for the application, go to Advanced Properties and try setting 'Load user profile' to true.

Comment: im sorry, but how i do that exactly?